# does anyone know how to make the amp-accordion close on hover?

Tags: amp-html

I am currently working on replacing regular HTML with amp-HTML. How do I go about making an amp-accordion close on hover?

I have tried many things such as making each part of the accordion's on hover `visibility: hidden`.

The accordion works fine, I just want it to close on hover instead of having to click it.

Comment: Can you share some code in full you have tried?

Comment: I talked directly to Amp Project and they said this was not possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the official [amp-accordion](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-accordion) guide, there's no mention that this is doable. I think that's because AMP doesn't allow most author-written javascripts. I would suggest to stick only what is mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I spoke with Amp pages and they said it wasn't possible as of yet, so I posted a request on github

Comment: in other words, it's not doable (yet).

Comment: Not as of yet, they may have something for amp-selector which is in experimental faze as of now.